# How make to nic bonding using curtin in maas

Tags: maas

I want to make nic bonding using curtin preseed in maas.
I tried ...:

```
vi /etc/maas/preseeds/curtin_userdata_ubuntu_amd64_generic_xenial
debconf_selections:
 maas: |
  {{for line in str(curtin_preseed).splitlines()}}
  {{line}}
  {{endfor}}
early_commands:
................................
network:
 version: 1
 config:

  - id: enp130s0f0
    mac_address: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    mtu: 1500
    name: enp130s0f0
    subnets:
    - type: manual
    type: physical

  - id: enp131s0f0
    mac_address: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    mtu: 1500
    name: enp131s0f0
    subnets:
    - type: manual
    type: physical

  - bond_interfaces:
    - enp130s0f0
    - enp131s0f0
    id: bond0
    mac_address: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    mtu: 1500
    name: bond0
    params:
      bond-mode: active-backup
    subnets:
    - address: 192.168.2.10/24
      type: manual
    type: bond
................................
```

Result :  No Error, No bond.
         Not exist bond config  in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/50-curtin-networking.cfg

How make to nic bonding using curtin in maas ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MAAS already supports configuring bonds. You dont have a need to send custom curtin preseed information, you can do the configuration you want in MAAS and it will handle it all automatically for you.

That said, make sure you are using the latest supported version of MAAS (2.3) with the latest images.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, if we have many machines and same network/storage configuration  , how make it at once ?